# Is there an OCR that can convert an image of a formula into a TeX markup?

Tags: math-mode, pdf, conversion, automation, tools

Is there an [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) software that can convert a graphical image (in PNG, GIF, TIFF, PDF... format) of a mathematical formula into the corresponding TeX markup?

Answer (score 14):

Yes. There is one that I knew.

[image]

More details, see [this link](http://www.sciaccess.net/en/InftyReader/).

Comment: There's also FFES (http://www.cs.queensu.ca/drl/ffes/), which along w/ Infty is mentioned at: http://www.tug.org/interest.html

Comment: The correct link to FFES (Freehand Formula Entry System) is https://www.cs.rit.edu/~rlaz/ffes/

Answer (score 4):

The [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) app can convert pictures of printed and handwritten math and convert it to LaTex. The new Mathpix desktop app that was recently released lets you take a screenshot of the equation on your desktop and copies the LaTex to the clipboard so you can just paste it into your LaTex/markdown editor.

Comment: It is also a Desktop app which takes screenshots and copies Latex to clipboard

Comment: @Sebastiano They also provide online version right now https://snip.mathpix.com/redstone-cold/notes/note-1/edit

Comment: @iMath Hi, and thank you for your comment. I have tried the online version but my humble opinion is that you can not copy many formulas but only some equations. Now I delete my old comment.