# Are there any tools for Image -> LaTeX?

Tags: programming

Are there any existing tools which take as

input: TypeSet Math Formula

output: LaTeX code which produces something similar to the existing math formula?

Googling "inverse LaTex" gets answers about inverse/matrix symbols.
  Googling "image to LaTeX" gets answers about inserting images in LaTeX

Thanks!

EDIT: Not duplicate of "OCR -> TeX". I don't need "handwriting -> TeX", for me, it suffices to do "rendered math formula -> TeX"

Comment: Possible duplicates: [What is the status of generating LaTeX from handwriting (i.e., OCR)?])http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1443/5764), [Is there an OCR that can convert an image of a formula into a TeX markup?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145048/5764)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to get the source code of a LaTeX rendered PDF file if one has the hard copy?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85683/5764)

Comment: What does "rendered math formula" represent? An image?

Comment: Werner: I have a PDF as input. I can render the PDF at arbitrary resolution. Generally (I may be wrong on this), I take OCR to mean "noisy text", whereas the "rendered math formulas" I have are "clean."