# Software to convert photograph to formatted or unformatted latex code

Tags: graphics, conversion, sourcecode

I am interested in undertaking a project to reprint rare and classic math and science books to make them available to researchers at low cost.

Books I can get a good PDF for are easy to do, but there are a few which are old and without any good PDF.

I would like to somehow take photos of my hardcopies and run a script which takes these photos in and returns a basic latex source for the output. Does anyone know of software which could help me?

(my apologies for bad tagging...I have no idea how this should be tagged)

Comment: [Infty Reader](http://www.sciaccess.net/en/InftyReader/) is a (non-free) software which seems to be able to do that.

Comment: Related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1443/what-is-the-status-of-generating-latex-from-handwriting-i-e-ocr https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145048/is-there-an-ocr-that-can-convert-an-image-of-a-formula-into-a-tex-markup